# Windows, cannot delete files immediately after service delete

Tags: windows, service, delete-file

I delete a windows service with a `sc.exe delete <serviceName>`.

Immediately after that, I delete the files owned by the service (an *exe* and a couple of *dlls*) and I cannot because these files are still locked.

I've found out that it works if I execute a sleep of 3 seconds (I wonder what is Windows doing for 3 seconds!) between the service delete and the files delete.

Is there some more elegant and secure solution?

Probably useless detail: I'm running this from `Inno Setup` on `Jenkins` on `Windows 7`

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you can kill the process(es) of that services to release the resources it has by typing these commands;

```
> $ServicePID = (get-wmiobject win32_service | where { $_.name -eq 'service name'}).processID
> Stop-Process $ServicePID -Force
```

Then, you can delete that service by typing as you can indicate:

```
> sc.exe delete <serviceName>
```

Comment: This would force us to install a `PowerShell` plugin on `Jenkins`, no thanks.